# EE - How do I make the current segment active using Category Tags?

Tags: expressionengine

I am using the channel:categories tag to pull in categories for a section navigation. This works fine, but I also would like to tag the current active category as the active item in the navigation for styling purposes:

**a class="active"**

I tried two approaches neither of which works.

Attempt 1 (per the [documentation](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/categories.html#examples)):

```
<a {if active} class="active"{/if} href="{path='internal-staff-center/{category_url_title}'}">{category_name}</a>
```

Attempt 2:

```
<a {if segment_2 == "{category_url_title}"}class="active"{/if}  href="{path='internal-staff-center/{category_url_title}'}">{category_name}</a>
```

I would appreciate some input from another viewpoint out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{path}` variable within Channel Categories will output a path using your category trigger word or the **C(n)** URL segment (C2, C15, etc). So it's doubtful that `{segment_2}` is actually your `category_url_title` ... it's more likely `{segment_3}`.

What is an example URL structure of these pages?

`{if segment_X == category_url_title}` should work so long as the comparison is correct.

Comment: Hi Derek, spot on. I was surprised that it didn't need all the quotes and brackets. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{if "{segment_2}" == "{category_url_title}"} class="current"{/if}
```

Comment: Woops, just had to correct the segment reference to `2` to match your example.

Comment: Hi Alex, this was close, but Derek got it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's funny. Sometimes it seems variables in conditionals need quotes, sometimes not. And if one compared variable is quoted, the other needs to be, too. Might just be me, though! :-P

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing. I tend to err on the side of not enough quotes and brackets. Ever learning. Thanks.

Comment: Just thought to add a link to this answer on the [**difference between quoted and unquoted comparison syntax**](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1515/22) since it explains the seemingly mysterious quotes/no-quotes thing.